# Why is tools:keep ignored when building App Bundles?

Tags: android, proguard, android-resources, android-app-bundle

In my Android *drawable* folder I have certain images that are never directly referenced from the code so Proguard flags them as unused and they are not included in the release build.

To include said images I created a file keep.xml and added the following code:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:keep="@drawable/*_thumb"
/>
```

When I now create a signed APK in Android Studio, everything works perfectly fine. In the Proguard-log (*\build\outputs\mapping\release\resources.txt*) file I can see the following lines and the images are now included in the build:

> @drawable/image01_thumb : reachable=true
> @drawable/image02_thumb : reachable=true

Before adding the keep.xml the log would tell me that the images are not reachable, so the keep.xml does definitely work for the APK.

**Here is the problem though:**
When I now create a signed App Bundle, then the Proguard log tells me that the images are again unreachable and so of course they are not included in the resulting App Bundle.

**Question:**
Why does Proguard behave differently when I create an App Bundle and how can I fix this?

I know there are ways to indicate Proguard that certain resources are used from within the code, but in my case that is not a proper solution and I would like to solve this using the keep.xml